# PathParam from previous websocket call is submitted

Tags: websocket, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I am using JavaEE 7 and Glassfish 4 as my project setup and I would like to use websockets. As browser I have used Chrome 35.0.1916.153. My endpoint should receive a message through websockets and broadcast this message to other users within the same group.

If I open two browser tabs which open websocket connections to different groups [e.g. first 1, then 2 (the order matters!)] everything works as expected. But when I call the broadcast method by the first tab (groupId=1) the groupId path parameter has the value 2. It looks like it is the last onOpen call's value.

In this call the Session object looks like this:

```
session = (org.glassfish.tyrus.core.SessionImpl) SessionImpl{
    uri=/test/group/1, <--
    id='0fcff8ae-7ff8-42e8-a9e9-03cbb1f62562', 
    endpoint=EndpointWrapper{
        endpointClass=null, 
        endpoint=org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint@59d91963, 
        uri='/test/group/2', <--
        contextPath='/test'
    }
}
```

The URI from session and endpoint differ which may result in the unwanted behavior.

Has anyone noted this yet?

My endpoint class looks like this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/group/{groupId}", 
                encoders = {MessageEncoder.class}, 
                decoders = {MessageDecoder.class})
public class GroupEndpoint {

private Map<String, Set<Session>> groups = GroupSingleton.getGroups();

@OnMessage
public void broadcast(@PathParam("groupId") String groupId, 
                            Message message, 
                            Session session) 
                                throws IOException, EncodeException {

    for (Session session : groups.get(groupId)) 
        session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(message); 
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(@PathParam("groupId") String groupId, 
                    Session session){ 

    if(groups.containsKey(property)){
        // then add peer to the list of viewers
        groups.get(groupId).add(session);
    }else{
        // if not start a new list
        Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
        sessions.add(session);         
        groups.put(groupId, sessions);
    }
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(@PathParam("groupId") String groupId, Session session) {

    groups.get(groupId).remove(session);

    if(groups.get(groupId).isEmpty())
        groups.remove(groupId);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, tracked as [TYRUS-203](https://java.net/jira/browse/TYRUS-203), which was fixed in Tyrus 1.1

Can you please useone of [promoted Glassfish](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/promoted/) builds?

Thanks,
Pavel